# Let $L/K$ be splititng field for $p$ and $a_1,a_2$ be two roots of $p$. Does then $a_1+a_2 \in K $ hold?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was reading about the Galois group of polynomials when I found the following:

Let K be a field, $p=x^2+bx+c \in K[x]$ a polynomial and $L$ the splitting field of $p$.
If we denote the roots of $p$ as $a_1,a_2 \in L$ it follows that $L=K(a_1)=K(a_2)$, since $a_1+a_2 =b \in K$.

My qeustion:
I don't really see why $a_1+a_2 \in K$.

Is this a typo, or am I missing something?

Comment: Try computing the roots of $p$ in terms of $b$ and $c$. Note that $b,c\in K$.

Comment: @Dave Oh right. But this is only true for a polynomial of second degree, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm sure there's *some* higher degree polynomials for which the sum of the roots is in $K$, but in general it won't hold.

Comment: @Dave Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its correct. All the coefficents of $p$ lie in $K$ since $p\in K[x]$, and since its quadratic, $b$ is the sum of its two roots, and $b\in K$, so $a_1+a_2\in K$. For example $x^2+x+1$. Look what Happens with the sum of its roots. Note that that always holds for second degree polynomials, not in general. For example $x^3-1$, the roots are $1, w, w^2$, and $1+w\not \in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give some comments on this question, since it is a bit more profound.

First of all, let me correct something. If you have a second degree polynomial $X^2 + bX + c$, the sum of the roots is $-b$ and not $b$.

In general, suppose you have a polynomial $f(X) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i X^i$ with coefficients in a field $\mathbb{K}$, and let $\mathbb{L}$ be a splitting field of $f$.

If $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n \in \mathbb{L}$ are the roots of $f$, with a  similar argument as Guillermo García Sáez's one can show:

- $a_0 = (-1)^n \prod_i \alpha_i$,
- $a_{n-1} = - \sum_i \alpha_i$,
- In general, one can obtain a formula for every $a_i$ in terms of the roots of the polynomial. This is related to the symmetric polynomials.

This implies that the sum of the roots of $f$ is always in $\mathbb{K}$, since it equals $-a_{n-1}$. The same holds for the product of the roots.

However, one can give a nicer proof of this fact using some Galois theory. In order to show that $\sum_i \alpha_i \in \mathbb{K}$ it is necessary and sufficient to show that, for every automorphism $\sigma \in \textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{L}/\mathbb{K})$, it holds that $\sigma(\sum_i \alpha_i) = \sum_i \alpha_i$.

It is well-known that every automorphism permutes the roots of a polynomial, so $\sigma(\alpha_i) = \alpha_{j(i)}$, for some permutation $j$ of $\{1, ..., n\}$. Hence,
$$ \sigma\left(\sum_i \alpha_i\right) = \sum_i \alpha_{j(i)} = \sum_i \alpha_i,$$
where in the last equality we used the fact that $j$ is a permutation, and addition is commutative.

Again, the same is true for the product of the roots.